# Probability of a specific outcome of a "Lottery" machine

Tags: probability

I play a particular phone game in which you battle against monsters with monsters of your own. One of the methods to get these monsters is an **in-game lottery machine**, that at the pull of a lever and the use of some in-game (or real life - this is a phone game, of course) currency, you are awarded a random monster out of a large pool of monsters.

In a general forum for this game, someone asked what the chances would be of pulling **four specific monsters** (not in a row, just total) if they used this machine **ten times**.

Each of these monsters is fairly rare, and is from a particular list of "event only" awards, of which there are 8. (So, 8 potential monsters, of which you want a specific one). It is worth noting that if you do get a monster you want, it is not removed from the pool, so you can effectively (depending entirely on the odds) pull the same monster multiple times.

Usually, the odds of pulling **any** of these "event only" awards is about $\frac{1}{15}$ on its own.

Based on this, $\frac{1}{15}$ times you will have a $\frac{1}{8}$ chance of getting the monster you want. So, the probability of getting the monster you want on a single roll would be

$P(M) = \frac{1}{120}$

However, you only get $10$ tries at this.

But we need this to happen at least four times. Not in a row, just four times out of ten. If you use the *Binomial Distribution* for something of this nature it is

$$\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1−p)^{n−k}$$

For us, out of $n = 10$ trials, and $k = 4$ successes, with $n - k = 6$ failures (I realize this is exact instead of the "at least four" scenario).

So for us this becomes (using *Mathematica*)

$$\binom{10}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{120}\right)^{4}\cdot\left(\frac{119}{120}\right)^{6} = 9.631381876198418\times 10^{-7}$$

So the probability of this happening exactly four times out of ten is approximately $9.63\times 10^{-6}\%$.

Is this thought process correct and, if so, how would you approach this as "at least four times out of ten" instead of "exactly four times out of ten"? Or at the approaches the same for all intents and purposes?

EDIT:

For "at least four times out of ten", would simply using the Binomial Distribution for each successful outcome higher than four (i.e. $k = 5,6,7,...,10$) and then adding them all together give you the correct probability, or is there something more to / something easier than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is along the right lines, but

- When you get to more than $4$ successes out of the $10$, the calculations become a lot messier (you need to consider all possible kinds of successes like "$2$ of monster *a*, $2$ of monster *b* and one each of monsters *c* and *d*", and there are too many such kinds), and
- For exactly $4$ successes, you need to consider failure as being *none* of the $4$ monsters you want, which would mean a failure probability of $1 - \frac{4}{120} = \frac{116}{120}$ instead of the $\frac{119}{120}$ you used.

An alternative approach here, which is simpler, is to count the probability that you *don't* get all four monsters you want. Thus, this is the probability that all $10$ uses of the machine were from a space of outcomes that only include some $3$ of your $4$ monsters, then account for overcounting those that actually come from only $2$, only $1$, or none — the inclusion-exclusion principle, essentially.

---

An approach that unifies both the above (but is ultimately equivalent) is to use *generating functions*, which I find is a neat way to organize your thinking and avoid errors, turning the problem into something mechanical instead. So let's do that.

Call the four monsters you want *a*, *b*, *c* and *d*. Or rather, let these letters stand for the outcome that when you use the lottery machine you get that particular monster, and *e* stand for the outcome that you get none of these four. Then as you have argued, $p_a = p_b = p_c = p_d = \frac{1}{120}$, and $p_e = 1 - (p_a + p_b + p_c + p_d) = \frac{116}{120}$.

We will consider the (exponential) generating function
$$A(z) = 1 + p_a z + p_a^2 \frac{z^2}{2!} + p_a^3 \frac{z^3}{3!} + \dots$$
where $n!$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ is the probability $p_a^n$ that in $n$ specific uses of the lottery machine, you get all *a*'s. Similarly define $B(z)$, $C(z)$ and $D(z)$ (they are all equal to $A(z)$), and finally 
$$E(z) = 1 + p_e z + p_e^2 \frac{z^2}{2!} + p_e^3 \frac{z^3}{31} + \dots.$$

Now as a success is an outcome, in ten (or in general, $n$) uses of the lottery machine in which *a* occurred at least once (so only the $z$ and higher-degree terms are to be taken, which means $A(z) - 1$), and so on, the probability of success is the $n!$ times the coefficient of $n$ in 
$$(A(z) - 1) (B(z) - 1) (C(z) - 1) (D(z) - 1) E(z)$$

Here, note that $A(z) = \exp(p_a z)$ (and $A(z) = B(z) = C(z) = D(z)$), and $E(z) = \exp(p_e z)$. So we're looking for the coefficients in 
$$(e^{p_az} - 1)^{4} e^{p_e z}$$
which, setting $p = p_a$ and $q = p_e = 1 - 4p$, is equal to
$$\begin{align}
e^{qz} (e^{pz} - 1)^4 
&= e^{qz} (e^{4pz} - 4e^{3pz} + 6e^{2pz} - 4e^{pz} + 1) \\
&= e^z - 4e^{(1-p)z} + 6e^{(1-2p)z} - 4e^{(1-3p)z} + e^{(1-4p)z} \\
\end{align}$$
in which $n!$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ is 
$$1 - 4(1-p)^n + 6(1-2p)^n - 4(1-3p)^n + (1-4p)^n \tag 1$$
which is exactly the calculation you'd have arrived at (possibly in fewer steps) if you thought out the inclusion-exclusion approach and didn't make mistakes.

[Note that your approach, of counting directly, is from this view simply a different way of finding the same coefficient in the same generating function: it is analogous to, and the calculation it gives is exactly the same as, not using the fact that the GF $pz + p^2\frac{z^2}{2!} + p^3\frac{z^3}{3!} + \dots$ is $e^{pz} - 1$, and just multiplying out the GFs directly.]

---

Anyway for your particular case, setting $n = 10$ and $p = \frac{1}{120}$ in $(1)$ gives [the answer to be](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+4%281-p%29%5En+%2B+6%281-2p%29%5En+-+4%281-3p%29%5En+%2B+%281-4p%29%5En+where+n+%3D+10+and+p+%3D+1%2F120&dataset=)
$$\frac{113421991391621}{5159780352000000000} \approx 0.0000219819 \approx 2.20 \times 10^{-5}
$$

which is unsurprisingly very close to the (much simpler to calculate) probability that each of the four monsters appears exactly once in the ten lotteries, [which is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2810+choose+4%29+%2824%29+p%5E4+%281-4p%29%5E6+where+p+%3D+1%2F120)
$$ \binom{10}{4} (4!) p^4 (1-4p)^6 = \frac{4163763247}{209952000000000} \approx 0.000019832 \approx 1.98 \times 10^{-5}$$
as getting each exactly once is the dominant way in which success can happen.

---

Edit: if what you actually want is the probability of at least one of monster *a* and at least three of monster *b*, then set $q = 1 - p_a - p_b$ and
$$
A(z) = p_az + p_a^2 \frac{z^2}{2!} + \dots = e^{pz} - 1\\
B(z) = p_b^3 \frac{z^3}{3!} + p_b^4 \frac{z^4}{4!} + \dots = e^{pz} - 1 -pz - p^2\frac{z^2}{2}\\
F(z) = 1 + qz + q^2\frac{z^2}{2!} + \dots = e^{qz}.$$

Then you're looking for $10!$ times the coefficient of $z^{10}$ in $A(z)B(z)F(z)$ which [gives the answer](https://github.com/shreevatsa/misc-math/blob/master/monsters.sage)
$$\frac{2355791478598987}{619173642240000000000} \approx 3.80 \times 10^{-6}$$

Comment: I didn't actually specify in the problem since I thought it would complicate it further, but the original asker who I tried to respond to asked for specifically "1 of monster a, 3 of monster b". This actually might be less (or more) complicated than having one of four options, because we would only have to choose "1 of monster a, 3 of monster b, exactly", instead of your example of all sets of possible outcomes. But of course across all cases the probability remains very, very small and both the methodology and a ballpark answer were all that I needed.

Comment: @Zodack: Added answer for your modified case (it's 6x smaller). (Note how the framework of EGFs is virtually identical.) The change doesn't really make it less complicated, even for direct counting: in the former case there were 27 kinds 1111, 2111, 2211, 2221, 2222, 3111, 3211, 3221, 3222, 3311, 3321, 3322, 3331, 4111, 4211, 4221, 4222, 4311, 4321, 4411, 5111, 5211, 5221, 5311, 6111, 6211, 7111 (and all their permutations). In the latter there are 28 kinds 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 43, 44, 45, 46, 53, 54, 55, 63, 64, 73.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. My background is in physics and I haven't taken a formal probability course of any kind (nor have I been instructed in any probability in my physics courses, which is a bit alarming to me), so actually getting into the meat of this was very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your calculation assumes that the 4 specified monsters are appearing in a specific order.
To correct that, you need to multiply by the number of permutations of 4 objects, which is 24.

Also, the 6 failure cases each have a probability of 116/120, not 119/120.

My calculation gives a figure of almost 2×10−5 for each of the 4 specified monsters appearing exactly once (but in any order) in the 10 attempts.

You are correct that, to get a figure that also allows for being even luckier and getting one or more of those 4 monsters more than once, we can add up the probabilities of those cases as well. However, those calculations get a bit more complex - I need to think about that one for a bit...

Comment: Just a confirmation: I too got the same figure for each of the $4$ appearing exactly once, so it's very likely correct. :-)